# HRegionInterface removed in Hbase1.1.1, replacement for that

Tags: java, hbase, mapr

We are moving from Hbase 0.94 to Hbase 1.1.1 version. We have our application code using HRegionInterface API and now it is not available in Hbase 1.1.1. Can anyone suggest me the alternate API to access HRegionServers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This interface was just removed.

> As a step to move internals to PB, so as to avoid the conversion for performance reason, we should remove the HRegionInterface. 
>   Therefore region server only supports ClientProtocol and AdminProtocol. Later on, HRegion can work with PB messages directly.

More details is here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-5889

If you use any methods from it, you can post them here. And somebody will be able to help you with finding out the alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Avseiytsev Dmitriy for highlighting the reason for change done in Hbase.

I managed to use org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.AdminProtos.AdminService.BlockingInterface for getting region info for a table and store file list for a particular region of a table.